# How to make tabWidget in left side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

How to make **layout** like this??
Create a Tab Widget on left side of the layout. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like it's a tab widget to me. You'll most likely want to use a ListFragment

Check out this tutorial [Here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/01/listfragment.html)

Your main activity will host a fragment, after an an item in your list is click you should be able to call something like getListView().getItemAtPosition or something similar. Pass that data to your activity and display it. Or you can just use two fragments, one would be a ListFragment and the other will be the rest of your content.

```
 @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

 getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);

 //Then pass your data into your Activity(if you need to)
 //

 }
```